# In Bohnanza: Gangsters, does the Mafia act in phase 4?

Tags: bohnanza

In Bohnanza: Gangsters, two of the beanfields are managed by the mafia.  The rules state that they immediately harvest their beans once they have a big enough harvest to get 3 or 2 coins (depending on the gangster).

There is also a rule that no player can harvest during phase 4 (the drawing of 3 cards).

Does the mafia harvest immediately during phase 4, or do they wait until the end of the phase 4 and then sell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the answer already.  You're just stumbling over the definition of "player".

The mafia are not players.

Players may not harvest during phase 4.

The mafia must harvest when they reach the specified amount of coin value, regardless of what phase it is.